# Need help calculating total salary of employees in my management system

Tags: python-3.x

I have no idea how to start but I am using information in a file called ('emp_details') which I keep opening when coding can anyone help me?

```
    def total_salary():
file=open('emp_details.txt','r')
tsalary = 0
for line in file:
    line.split('\n')
    item = line.split(',')
    salary: List(str) = item[1:4]
    tsalary = tsalary + str(salary)
print('The total salary for all employees in the system is: ',tsalary)
anykey = input("Enter any key to return main menu")
mainMenu()
```

I have a file called 'emp_details' this contain all the information including the salary of each employee. I am trying to calculate the total salary of all employees.

this is the file that has been read in.

```
    #EMP_NO, EMP_NAME, AGE, POSITION, SALARY, YRS_EMP   
    001, Peter Smyth, 26, Developer, 29000, 4
    002, Samuel Jones, 23, Developer, 24000, 1
    003, Laura Stewart, 41, DevOps, 42000, 15
    004, Paul Jones, 24, Analyst, 21000, 2
    005, Simon Brown, 52, Developer, 53000, 18
    006, George Staples, 42, Tester, 42000, 12
    007, Greg Throne, 57, DevOps, 50000, 23
    008, Aston Bently, 27, Tester, 33000, 5
    009, Ben Evans, 32, DevOps, 38000, 2
    010, Emma Samson, 23, DevOps, 22000, 1
    011, Stephanie Beggs, 43, Tester, 19000, 9
    012, Sarah McQuillin, 47, DevOps, 23000, 5
    013, Grace Corrigan, 48, Analyst, 44000, 16
    014, Simone Mills, 32, DevOps, 32000, 11
    015, Martin Montgomery, 28, Analyst, 28000, 3
```

Comment: What file? What do you code? What do you want to achieve? Too many what's and no info. Please provide some sample data and explain what you want to do.

Comment: there you go I have edited my original post.

Comment: Share a sample of the file you are reading in the code.

Comment: Your identation is wrong, beside that your code is faulty, f.e. `item(1:4)`is not valid python. Your function is never called, `mainMenue` is undefined and so on. Please read and provide a [mcve] - Questions that do not show some effort will be downvoted and closed - your's is currently on this way. Why should **I** invest my spare time and smarts to fix your code, if it is not important enough to you, to spend at least some effort into it?

Comment: sorry I'm new to python and trying to understand it all while completing this project.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you are trying to reinvent a wheel of sorts(even if you don't know there is a wheel). If you utilize pandas and import as a csv, which this seems to be, this can be done in 3 lines;

```
import pandas as pd

f = pd.read_csv('emp_details.txt', sep=',', names = ['EMP_NO', 'EMP_NAME', 'AGE', 'POSITION', 'SALARY', 'YRS_EMP'])
df = pd.DataFrame(f)
Total = df['SALARY'].sum()
```

edit: after some testing I realize the txt extension makes it necessary to skip the first line, so it turns into;

```
import pandas as pd

f = pd.read_csv('emp_details.txt', sep=',',skiprows = [0], names = ['EMP_NO', 'EMP_NAME', 'AGE', 'POSITION', 'SALARY', 'YRS_EMP'])
df = pd.DataFrame(f)
Total = df['SALARY'].sum()
```

Comment: okay, you'll need to install this module. It is extremely useful for this exact scenario and many others. [Try pip installing pandas](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#use-pip-for-installing) and try the code again.